# JavaFX Frisbee movement on mouse / drag event

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

I have a question regarding the correct way to implement a mouse drag event in JavaFX.

My `playGame()` method currently makes use of `onMouseClicked`, however this is just a placeholder for now

Ideally, I would like the 'frisbee' to be "tossed" in the direction of the mouse drag.

What would be a good way to do this?

```
package FrisbeeToss;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FrisbeeTossMain extends Application {

private Text info = new Text();
private Entity frisbee, target;

private static final int APP_W = 800;
private static final int APP_H = 600;

private static class Entity extends Parent {
    public Entity(double x, double y, double r, Color c) {
        setTranslateX(x);
        setTranslateY(y);
        Circle circ = new Circle(r, c);
        getChildren().add(circ);
    }
}

private Parent createContent() {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(APP_W, APP_H);

    info.setTranslateX(50);
    info.setTranslateY(50);

    target = new Entity(APP_W /2, APP_H /2, 75, Color.RED);
    frisbee = new Entity(APP_W -20, APP_H -20, 60, Color.GREEN);

    root.getChildren().addAll(info, target, frisbee);

    return root;
}

private void checkCollision(Entity a, Entity b){
    if (a.getBoundsInParent().intersects(b.getBoundsInParent())) {
        info.setText("Target caught frisbee!");
    }
    else {
        info.setText("");
    }
}

private void playGame() {
    frisbee.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("Frisbee clicked");

        checkCollision(frisbee, target);
    });
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());

    primaryStage.setTitle("Frisbee Toss");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    playGame();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Animation**

There are a few ways this could be done, but taking the concept of a Frisbee into consideration transitions would work well. There's an official tutorial here:

- [Animation Basics - Transitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#BEIIJJJB)

From those available, the `PathTransition` would work well. By converting the direction the user "tosses" the Frisbee in, you can generate a `Path` that the Frisbee `Node` can follow. By modifying the cycles and applying reversal you could also make the Frisbee behave like a boomerang

As Frisbee's spin, you could also take advantage of a `RotationTransition` and apply it alongside the movement along the path

---

**Applying the animation (s)**

You can apply the above transition(s) with just a `mouseReleased` event on the Frisbee, but as you've specifically mentioned dragging, I've modified your code below to show both approaches. One with the released event and the other using drag-and-drop

If you want to read more on the drag-and-drop feature, it's covered here:

- [Drag-and-Drop Feature in JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag_drop_feature.htm)

---

**Minor changes made to original source**

In the implementations below, I've removed your `Entity` class replacing it with a `Circle` as the `Entity` wasn't adding anything, with the purpose seeming to be just creating a `Circle`

I've also removed the `static` declarations. In this particular example there is no benefit to having or removing them, but the `static` keyword should only be used where it needs to be. Hopefully this popular post can better explain why:

- [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

---

**Implementations:**

I've added comments to clarify some steps but if anything isn't clear, or you have some improvements please add a comment

*mouseReleased approach:*

```
public class FrisbeeTossMain extends Application {
    private Pane root;
    private Text info = new Text();
    private Circle frisbee, target;
    private PathTransition transition;

    private final int APP_W = 800;
    private final int APP_H = 600;
    private final double frisbeeX = APP_W -20;
    private final double frisbeeY = APP_H -20;

    private Parent createContent() {
        root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(APP_W, APP_H);

        info.setTranslateX(50);
        info.setTranslateY(50);

        target = new Circle(75, Color.RED);
        target.setLayoutX(APP_W /2);
        target.setLayoutY(APP_H /2);

        frisbee = new Circle(60, Color.GREEN);
        frisbee.setLayoutX(frisbeeX);
        frisbee.setLayoutY(frisbeeY);
        frisbee.setFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
                new Stop[] { new Stop(0, Color.BLACK), new Stop(1, Color.GREEN)}));

        SimpleBooleanProperty isFrisbeeVisuallyCollidingWithTarget = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        frisbee.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            isFrisbeeVisuallyCollidingWithTarget.set(
                    Shape.intersect(frisbee, target).getBoundsInParent().getWidth() >= 0 ? true : false);
        });

        isFrisbeeVisuallyCollidingWithTarget.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue && transition != null){
                //Stop the animation making it appear as though the frisbee was caught
                transition.stop();
            }
        });

        info.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(isFrisbeeVisuallyCollidingWithTarget)
                .then("Target caught frisbee!").otherwise(""));
        root.getChildren().addAll(info, target, frisbee);

        return root;
    }

    private void playGame() {
        frisbee.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            //Starting point for the line
            double fromX = frisbeeX - frisbee.getRadius();
            double fromY = frisbeeY - frisbee.getRadius();

            //Only "throw" the frisbee if the user has released outside of the frisbee itself
            if(frisbee.getBoundsInParent().contains(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())){
                return;
            }

            //Create a path between the frisbee and released location
            Line line = new Line(fromX, fromY, event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            transition = new PathTransition(Duration.seconds(1), line, frisbee);
            transition.setAutoReverse(true); //Set the node to reverse along the path
            transition.setCycleCount(2); //2 cycles, first to navigate the path, second to return
            frisbee.relocate(0, 0); //Allow the path to control the location of the frisbee

            RotateTransition rotateTransition =
                    new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), frisbee);
            rotateTransition.setByAngle(360f);
            rotateTransition.setCycleCount(2);
            rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

            rotateTransition.play();
            transition.play();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Frisbee Toss");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        playGame();
    }
}
```

---

*drag-and-drop implementation:*

The only difference is from the above is within the `playGame` method:

```
private void playGame() {
    frisbee.setId("frisbee");

    frisbee.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
        Dragboard db = frisbee.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        // Store node ID in order to know what is dragged.
        content.putString(frisbee.getId());
        db.setContent(content);
        event.consume();
    });

    root.setOnDragOver(event -> {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
        event.consume();
    });

    root.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
        //Starting point for the line
        double fromX = frisbeeX - frisbee.getRadius();
        double fromY = frisbeeY - frisbee.getRadius();

        //Only "throw" the frisbee if the user has released outside of the frisbee itself
        if(frisbee.getBoundsInParent().contains(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())){
            return;
        }

        //Create a path between the frisbee and released location
        Line line = new Line(fromX, fromY, event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
        transition = new PathTransition(Duration.seconds(1), line, frisbee);
        transition.setAutoReverse(true); //Set the node to reverse along the path
        transition.setCycleCount(2); //2 cycles, first to navigate the path, second to return
        frisbee.relocate(0, 0); //Allow the path to control the location of the frisbee

        transition.setOnFinished(finishedEvent -> {
            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            event.consume();
        });
        transition.play();
    });
}
```

---

**Adding rotation:**

The rotation can be applying by pre-pending the below snippet before playing the `PathTransition`:

```
RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), frisbee);
rotateTransition.setByAngle(360f);
rotateTransition.setCycleCount(2);
rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
rotateTransition.play();
```

You can make the rotation more notice-able by applying a `GradientFill` to the Frisbee, as opposed to a block color

E.g:

```
frisbee.setFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
    new Stop[] { new Stop(0, Color.BLACK), new Stop(1, Color.GREEN)}));
```

---

**Visual output**

Order: `mouseReleased | drag-and-drop | mouseReleased with rotation`

*(Note the cursor change in the drag-and-drop implementation)*

[image: Frisbee Released]
[image: Frisbee Drag]
[image: Frisbee Released with rotation]